# Hiding and showing div causes list in this div to scroll to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am kind of simulating that I have multiple pages by defining 2 divs that each act as a page. Only one page at the time is shown. Those divs are:

1. divProjectList
2. divProjectListItem

When the user opens the website, the div 'divProjectList' is shown. This div contains an un-ordered list with projects. This is a long list, so it is sortable.

As soon the user clicks an item from the list, I do a `$('#divProjectList').hide()` followed by a `$('#divProjectListItem').show()`. The list is now invisible for the user and instead is presented with project details for the item he selected from the list.

As soon as the user clicks the close button it works the other way around. The project details page is being hidden and the project list page is being shown again.

If the user scrolled down a bit (or a couple of pages) then the project list is scrolled back to the first item and the item that he clicked is now out of view.

I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/py7zemLo/) that has a hide- and show-button and a list which simulates the behavior that I described above.

I would like to know if it is expected behavior what I see here and how I could circumvent this. For now I solved it by doing a $.ScrollTo:

```
$('#' + currentProjectId).ScrollTo({duration: 0, offsetTop: 151})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This jquery code reminds you where you scrolled to, and puts you back there when you press the show button:

http://jsfiddle.net/py7zemLo/1/

jquery:

```
var scroll;

    $("#btnHide").on("click", function (e) {
        scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        // $("#divOptions").hide();
        $("#divOptions").css('display', 'none');
    })

    $("#btnShow").on("click", function (e) {
        // $("#divOptions").show();
        $("#divOptions").css('display', 'block');
        if ( scroll !== null ) {
            $(document).scrollTop(scroll);
        }
    })
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Stefan! Your code is more or less what I had done in my code, see my fp. I found out that I needed to use a time out of 100ms to make it work all the time.